# How to use JBullet in LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have got a problem, because I wan't to add collision detection to my 3d game, which I am developing in Java, using the Lightweight Java Game Library (LWJGL). I have googled a bit, and I have found this interesting library, called JBullet, which is a port of Bullet for C/C++. But I can't find **any** tutorials covering, how to add collision detection to my 3d shapes in LWJGL. Is there any simple way to do it, or please direct me to a tutorial, covering that topic.

Comment: Keep in mind that physics and graphics are not related; how you _draw_ a mesh has nothing to do with how you will do your collision (which often will be a simpler geometric shape), generally.  It might be easier to find what you're looking for if you stop worrying about LWJGL specifically and just look for docs on JBullet alone.

Answer (score 6):

The library comes with examples of how to use it. All of the source code for the [webstart examples](http://jbullet.advel.cz/) comes with the library.

There's also a [tutorials section](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php?title=Documentation#Tutorials) in the wiki page for jBullet.

Further, most of the tutorials for the c++ version are applicable to the Java port. You will just need to modify the class and function names to work with the Java syntax and naming conventions.

Comment: For the record, the tutorials section and the webstart examples are pretty crap for the majority of implementations that most people would want to use JBullet for.